Material-UI , Control hover in each rows
I have script like this ,
<TableBody sx={{"& .MuiTableRow-root:hover": {
   backgroundColor: "#DDDDDD"
 }}} >
<TableRow><TableCell>test1</TableCell></TableRow>
<TableRow><TableCell>test2</TableCell></TableRow>
<TableRow><TableCell>test3</TableCell></TableRow>
</TableBody>

it works correctly when mouse comes to the row the row color changes.
However now I want to change the color for each row.
When mouse pointer comes to test1 backgroundColor will be "#FFFFFF"
When mouse pointer comes to test2 backgroundColor will be "#DDDDDD"
When mouse pointer comes to test2 backgroundColor will be "#222222"
I guess I should set the sx in each TableRow, but I guess & .MuiTableRow-root:hover should be changed.
How can I make this?

You need to set custom sx for each row using '&.MuiTableRow-root:hover' selector like this:
<Table>
  <TableBody>
    <TableRow
      sx={{
        '&.MuiTableRow-root:hover': {
          backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        },
      }}
    >
      <TableCell>test1</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
      sx={{
        '&.MuiTableRow-root:hover': {
          backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
        },
      }}
    >
      <TableCell>test2</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
      sx={{
        '&.MuiTableRow-root:hover': {
          backgroundColor: '#222222',
        },
      }}
    >
      <TableCell>test3</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  </TableBody>
</Table>

You can take a look at this StackBlitz for a live working example.
